# Error creating attributed string- Swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to create a attributed string and add it to a textfield along with a non attributed string. When I try to create the attributed string I get the exception :

> Extra Argument String in Call.

Should be self explanatory but can't see it, code is

```
let theString : NSString = "Correct Answers: "
        let labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)
        let attributes : Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : labelFont]

//Exception thrown here
var attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Foo", attributes:attributes);

textfield.text = attrString + "blah blah blah";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unwrap your "labelFont" for the attributes.

Also, you can't do

```
attrString + "blah blah blah"
```

because you can't directly add a String and a NSAttributedString.

You can use a NSMutableAttributedString:

```
let labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : labelFont!]
var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Foo", attributes: attributes)
let newString = NSAttributedString(string: " blah blah blah")
attrString.appendAttributedString(newString)
println(attrString.description)
```